# Pivot Multiple Columns on Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am new to SQL and learning as I go.  I am trying to pivot a table based on 2 column headers.

My current file headers are Year, Type, Facility, Pay Period, Cost Center, Job Class, Hours, Dollars, Units.

I would like to create a pivoted table that separates Hours, Dolls, and Units into columns but by Year and Type.

The ideal end column header templates would be: Facility, Pay Period, Cost Center, Job Class, Year - Type Hours, Year - Type Dollars, Year - Type Units.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you specify what SQL engine you will be using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: Could you please provide sample input data and output data and any work you have done already.

Comment: So far all I have done is make temp tables WHERE [year] = '2014' and [type] = 'actual' and done the same for each year and each type. Then brought in all columns and left joined on common properties for each temp table and column headers

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could provide some sample data from your input table.

Comment: I would love to. I just don't know what is and is not relevant. My current code runs about 500 lines across 8 views. with inputs from about 10 tables

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pivot, you can use SUM (or MAX depending on datatype) with CASE to build your columns dynamically.

Since you did not provide any data i just made up some and used all ints for brevity.

```
--Sample Data
CREATE TABLE #test ([Year] INT, [Type] int, Facility int, [Pay Period] int, [Cost Center] int, [Job Class] int, [Hours] int, Dollars int, Units int)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
(2013, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10, 15),
(2013, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 20, 16),
(2013, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 30, 17),
(2014, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 40, 18),
(2014, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 9, 50, 19),
(2014, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, 20),
(2014, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 70, 10),
(2015, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 80, 11),
(2015, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 90, 12),
(2015, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10, 13),
(2015, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 20, 14),
(2016, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 30, 15),
(2016, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 8, 40, 16),
(2016, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 9, 50, 17),
(2016, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 60, 18)


DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Build column variable using distinct Year, Type combinations for each year and type combination.
WITH cols AS 
(   SELECT  y.[Year],
            t.[Type]
    FROM    #test y, #test t
)
SELECT  @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',','') 
            + CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = ',[Year],' AND [Type] = ',[Type],' THEN [Hours] END) AS ',QUOTENAME(CONCAT([Year],' ',[Type],' - Hours'))) + ',' 
            + CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = ',[Year],' AND [Type] = ',[Type],' THEN [Dollars] END) AS ',QUOTENAME(CONCAT([Year],' ',[Type],' - Dollars'))) + ',' 
            + CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = ',[Year],' AND [Type] = ',[Type],' THEN [Units] END) AS ',QUOTENAME(CONCAT([Year],' ',[Type],' - Units')))
FROM    cols
GROUP BY [Year], [Type]
ORDER BY [Year], [Type];

-- Build dynamic sql that will select common fields, sum the dynamic columns, and group the data
SET @Sql = N'
    SELECT [Facility], [Pay Period], [Cost Center], [Job Class],'
    + @Columns + 
    'FROM #test
    GROUP BY [Facility], [Pay Period], [Cost Center], [Job Class]
'

-- Execute dyanamic query
EXEC(@Sql)
```